# Get TypeError When deploying A Mean.js Project into Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, deployment

This is an old `mean.js` project. The project `node` version `4.4.4`. I can run this project on my local machine using `node 10.24.1`.

When I deploy this project in `heroku`, many `TypeErrors` come in `terminal` while `node-modules` packages downloading. I followed some answers to solve this problem but unfortunately I can not succeed that is why I ask here.

My `package-lock` file is updated.

The `Build Logs` are as follows:

```
Enumerating objects: 28099, done.
Counting objects: 100% (28099/28099), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (15109/15109), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28099/28099), 58.86 MiB | 343.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 28099 (delta 10970), reused 27836 (delta 10797), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Deleting 1 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  4.4.4
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   3.8.x
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 4.4.4...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 4.4.4...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 3.8.x (replacing 2.15.1)...
remote:        npm 3.8.x installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1101-aws
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--production=false" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_648a0567/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v4.4.4
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
remote:        npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:455:12)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:7
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:118:7)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:135:20)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1101-aws
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--production=false" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_648a0567/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v4.4.4
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
remote:        npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:455:12)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:7
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:118:7)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:135:20)
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     at /tmp/build_648a0567/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
remote:        npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_648a0567/npm-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

**package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "...",
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.4",
    "npm": "3.8.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "debug": "grunt debug",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.9.0",
    "bower": "~1.3.8",
    "chalk": "~0.5",
    "compression": "~1.2.0",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.1.0",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^2.1.1",
    "consolidate": "~0.10.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "forever": "~0.11.0",
    "glob": "~4.0.5",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "helmet": "~0.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.12.0",
    "method-override": "~2.3.0",
    "mongoose": "4.7.3",
    "morgan": "~1.4.1",
    "multer": "^1.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "~2.4.1",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-facebook": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "~1.0.2",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.6.8",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "stripe": "^4.6.0",
    "swig": "~1.4.1",
    "validator": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-env": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-karma": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^2.0.2",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.4.2",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "should": "^8.3.1",
    "supertest": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

As this project is run on `node 10.24.1` on my local machine, it can build on `heroku` if `heroku's` `node version` is downgraded into `10.24.1` at runtime (if possible), I assume but I am not sure.

Please anyone answer this question or suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node.js 4.4.4](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.4.4/) is absolutely *ancient*.

It doesn't even show up on [this page of releases](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/), which says in part:

> After six months, odd-numbered releases (9, 11, etc.) become unsupported, and even-numbered releases (10, 12, etc.) move to *Active LTS* status and are ready for general use. *LTS* release status is "long-term support", which typically guarantees that critical bugs will be fixed for a total of 30 months.

Version 4.4 is well beyond its maintenance window, and I *strongly* urge you to upgrade this project.

Having said that, there's a good chance you can get Heroku to run Node.js 10 to match your local version. Heroku [only officially supports the current and active LTS releases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#supported-runtimes), but [it doesn't prevent you from using older releases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#other-available-runtimes):

> Since Heroku is based on a standard Ubuntu Linux stack, you can run most Node versions (`>= 0.10.0`) on the platform. However, the testing and support focus of the buildpack will be oriented around active LTS and Stable releases.

Update the `engines` section in your `package.json`:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  },
```

I have also removed the `npm` version here, which should cause Heroku to use whatever version is bundled with the latest Node.js 10.x release.

Commit this change, then redeploy.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for your informative answer. I have already built successfully with `node:10.24.1` and `npm:6.14.12` but now the fact I am facing is the view is blank and the `heroku logs --tail` is as
`: Idling
: State changed from up to down
: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
: Process exited with status 143
: Unidling
: State changed from down to starting
: Starting process with command ./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 server.js
warn: --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
: warn: --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms`

Comment: I run this command `heroku run node_modules/forever/bin/forever start server.js` to increase `forever minUptime`. The output is `Running node_modules/forever/bin/forever start server.js on ... up, run.3270 (Free)
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: server.js`

Comment: @mdmostafa, `forever` shouldn't be required on Heroku. If you can't find an existing question that solves this problem, feel free to ask a new one. You'll need to provide a bit more information about what `server.js` does.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I asked about another issue of this app. Please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635897/blank-page-shows-in-web-view-when-node-env-is-production-in-nodeexpress-app if you have time. Thanks!