# Blank Page Shows In Web View When NODE_ENV Is Production In Node+Express App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

This is an old versioned project and it is at running stage in local machine connecting with `MongoDB Atlas`. When I deploy my `mean.js` app built with `node`, `express` to `heroku`, the build is successful but the thing is the web view is like blank page. I followed some answers but can not be succeeded that is why I am asking here.

The `heroku logs` are like below:

```
2022-03-25T14:23:37.319654+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2022-03-25T14:23:38.549415+00:00 app[web.1]: MEAN.JS application started on port 54773
2022-03-25T14:23:38.689108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-25T14:58:50.628521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-03-25T14:58:50.647968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-03-25T14:58:53.472314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-03-25T14:58:53.727153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-03-27T10:19:41.605379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2022-03-27T10:19:41.621739+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2022-03-27T10:19:46.139293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 server.js`
2022-03-27T10:19:47.752377+00:00 app[web.1]: warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
2022-03-27T10:19:47.753954+00:00 app[web.1]: warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
2022-03-27T10:19:48.066056+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2022-03-27T10:19:49.476778+00:00 app[web.1]: MEAN.JS application started on port 51271
2022-03-27T10:19:49.960520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-27T10:19:52.993168+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=7d524d13-9d58-4325-b716-533e315e5182 fwd="202.136.89.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2317ms status=304 bytes=251 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:19:54.912293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=649453b1-a97b-420e-8151-8257fa29f21e fwd="202.136.89.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=449ms status=304 bytes=338 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:21:36.908951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=a3f03000-8e6d-4788-a1c8-837abbfc3c8a fwd="52.114.32.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=429ms status=200 bytes=1485 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:21:37.564811+00:00 app[web.1]: ******** Error status = 404 *********
2022-03-27T10:21:37.590828+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=275de4ef-fc8d-4dfa-baab-51cc2c229966 fwd="52.114.32.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=41ms status=200 bytes=32541 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:21:37.769165+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/img/brand/logo.png" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=0637558c-9d13-44eb-bb5b-c00923a7a8fa fwd="52.114.32.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=220ms status=302 bytes=521 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:21:46.126674+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=a07f79b2-020e-4681-868d-9549f8b71ffe fwd="123.108.244.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=388ms status=200 bytes=1485 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:21:49.478805+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=24e953a9-3954-4893-9959-563c8e69e375 fwd="123.108.244.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=201ms status=200 bytes=32417 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:21:56.564353+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=6f0ac9f8-1d73-44b7-82ff-0703afcf63d6 fwd="123.108.244.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=566ms status=304 bytes=251 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:21:58.040405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=9e866946-73fe-4605-8f4e-378770580d72 fwd="123.108.244.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=393ms status=304 bytes=338 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:22:21.948625+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=ad4240cc-e034-4bbc-95ad-91cfe723c054 fwd="123.108.244.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=591ms status=304 bytes=251 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:22:23.520792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=48a70fe8-7ed8-48e2-b012-926dad370e37 fwd="123.108.244.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=402ms status=304 bytes=338 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:23:12.398361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=60502b48-426f-448d-9750-985963f64ac6 fwd="123.108.244.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=602ms status=304 bytes=251 protocol=https
2022-03-27T10:23:13.725374+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=607dac79-fc9a-43c8-b91e-c71a7fa2303c fwd="123.108.244.230" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=419ms status=304 bytes=338 protocol=https
```

**server.js**

```
'use strict';
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var init = require('./config/init')(),
    config = require('./config/config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    chalk = require('chalk');
    mongoose.Promise = Promise;

/**
 * Main application entry file.
 * Please note that the order of loading is important.
 */

// console.log('env===', process.env.MONGO_URI);
// console.log('config', config.db);

var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(chalk.red('Could not connect to MongoDB!'));
        console.log(chalk.red(err));
    }
}, {
    useMongoClient: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// Init the express application
var app = require('./config/express')(db);

// Bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')();

// Start the app by listening on <port>
app.listen(config.port);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;

// Logging initialization
console.log('MEAN.JS application started on port ' + config.port);
```

**express.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),
    express = require('express'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    compress = require('compression'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    config = require('./config'),
    consolidate = require('consolidate'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports = function(db) {
    // Initialize express app
    var app = express();

    // Globbing model files
    config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/models/**/*.js').forEach(function(modelPath) {
        require(path.resolve(modelPath));
    });

    // Setting application local variables
    app.locals.title = config.app.title;
    app.locals.description = config.app.description;
    app.locals.keywords = config.app.keywords;
    app.locals.facebookAppId = config.facebook.clientID;
    app.locals.jsFiles = config.getJavaScriptAssets();
    app.locals.cssFiles = config.getCSSAssets();

    //================= start our custom variable=====================================
    // Setting application local variables for admin
    app.locals.adminJsFiles = config.getAdminJavaScriptAssets();
    app.locals.adminCssFiles = config.getAdminCSSAssets();

    //Setting application local variables for theme
    app.locals.themeJsFiles = config.getThemeJavaScriptAssets();
    app.locals.themeCssFiles = config.getThemeCSSAssets();
    //================= end our custom variable=====================================

    // Passing the request url to environment locals
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.url = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + req.url;
        next();
    });

    // Should be placed before express.static
    app.use(compress({
        filter: function(req, res) {
            return (/json|text|javascript|css/).test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
        },
        level: 9
    }));

    // Showing stack errors
    app.set('showStackError', true);

    // Set swig as the template engine
    app.engine('server.view.html', consolidate[config.templateEngine]);

    // Set views path and view engine
    app.set('view engine', 'server.view.html');
    app.set('views', './app/views');

    // Environment dependent middleware
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        // Enable logger (morgan)
        app.use(morgan('dev'));

        // Disable views cache
        app.set('view cache', false);
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        app.locals.cache = 'memory';
    }

    // Request body parsing middleware should be above methodOverride
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());

    // CookieParser should be above session
    app.use(cookieParser());

    // Express MongoDB session storage
    app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        secret: config.sessionSecret,
        store: new MongoStore({
            mongooseConnection: db.connection,
            collection: config.sessionCollection
        })
    }));

    // use passport session
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    // connect flash for flash messages
    app.use(flash());

    // Use helmet to secure Express headers
    app.use(helmet.xframe());
    app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
    app.use(helmet.nosniff());
    app.use(helmet.ienoopen());
    app.disable('x-powered-by');

    // Setting the app router and static folder
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

    // Globbing routing files
    config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/**/*.js').forEach(function(routePath) {
        require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
    });

    // Assume 'not found' in the error msgs is a 404. this is somewhat silly, but valid, you can do whatever you like, set properties, use instanceof etc.
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        // If the error object doesn't exists
        if (!err) return next();

        // Log it
        console.error(err.stack);

        // Error page
        res.status(500).render('500', {
            error: err.stack
        });
    });

    // Assume 404 since no middleware responded
    app.use(function(req, res) {
        //res.status(404).render('404', {
        //  url: req.originalUrl,
        //  error: 'Not Found'
        //});
        console.log('******** Error status = 404 *********');
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'secure') {
        // Log SSL usage
        console.log('Securely using https protocol');

        // Load SSL key and certificate
        var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./config/sslcerts/key.pem', 'utf8');
        var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./config/sslcerts/cert.pem', 'utf8');

        // Create HTTPS Server
        var httpsServer = https.createServer({
            key: privateKey,
            cert: certificate
        }, app);

        // Return HTTPS server instance
        return httpsServer;
    }

    // Return Express server instance
    return app;
};
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Unified Watch Object
    var watchFiles = {
        serverViews: ['app/views/**/*.*'],
        serverJS: ['gruntfile.js', 'server.js', 'config/**/*.js', 'app/**/*.js'],
        clientViews: ['public/modules/**/views/**/*.html', 'public/themes/**/views/**/*.html'],
        clientJS: ['public/js/*.js', 'public/modules/**/*.js', 'public/themes/**/*.js'],
        clientCSS: ['public/modules/**/*.css'],
        mochaTests: ['app/tests/**/*.js']
    };

    // Project Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            serverViews: {
                files: watchFiles.serverViews,
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            serverJS: {
                files: watchFiles.serverJS,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            clientViews: {
                files: watchFiles.clientViews,
                options: {
                    livereload: true,
                }
            },
            clientJS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientJS,
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            clientCSS: {
                files: watchFiles.clientCSS,
                tasks: ['csslint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            all: {
                src: watchFiles.clientJS.concat(watchFiles.serverJS),
                options: {
                    jshintrc: true
                }
            }
        },
        csslint: {
            options: {
                csslintrc: '.csslintrc',
            },
            all: {
                src: watchFiles.clientCSS
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            production: {
                options: {
                    mangle: false
                },
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.min.js': 'public/dist/application.js'
                }
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            combine: {
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.min.css': '<%= applicationCSSFiles %>'
                }
            }
        },
        nodemon: {
            dev: {
                script: 'server.js',
                options: {
                    ext: 'js,html',
                    watch: watchFiles.serverViews.concat(watchFiles.serverJS)
                }
            },
            debug: {
                script: 'server.js',
                options: {
                    nodeArgs: ['--inspect'],
                    ext: 'js,html',
                    watch: watchFiles.serverViews.concat(watchFiles.serverJS)
                }
            }
        },

        ngAnnotate: {
            production: {
                files: {
                    'public/dist/application.js': '<%= applicationJavaScriptFiles %>'
                }
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            default: ['nodemon:dev', 'watch'],
            debug: ['nodemon:debug', 'watch'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true,
                limit: 10
            }
        },
        env: {
            test: {
                NODE_ENV: 'test'
            },
            secure: {
                NODE_ENV: 'secure'
            }
        },
        mochaTest: {
            src: watchFiles.mochaTests,
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec',
                require: 'server.js'
            }
        },
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
            }
        }
    });

    // Load NPM tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Making grunt default to force in order not to break the project.
    grunt.option('force', true);

    // A Task for loading the configuration object
    grunt.task.registerTask('loadConfig', 'Task that loads the config into a grunt option.', function () {
        var init = require('./config/init')();
        var config = require('./config/config');

        grunt.config.set('applicationJavaScriptFiles', config.assets.js);
        grunt.config.set('applicationCSSFiles', config.assets.css);
    });

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['lint', 'concurrent:default']);

    // Debug task.
    grunt.registerTask('debug', ['lint', 'concurrent:debug']);

    // Secure task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('secure', ['env:secure', 'lint', 'concurrent:default']);

    // Lint task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('lint', ['jshint', 'csslint']);

    // Build task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['lint', 'loadConfig', 'ngAnnotate', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);

    // Test task.
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['env:test', 'mochaTest', 'karma:unit']);
};
```

**Procfile** (Previous)

```
web: ./node_modules/.bin/forever -m 5 server.js
```

**Procfile** (Updated)

```
web: node server.js
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "...",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.24.1",
    "npm": "6.14.12"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "grunt",
    "debug": "grunt debug",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.9.0",
    "bower": "~1.3.8",
    "chalk": "~0.5",
    "compression": "~1.2.0",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.1.0",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^2.1.1",
    "consolidate": "~0.10.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "forever": "~0.11.0",
    "glob": "~4.0.5",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "helmet": "~0.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.12.0",
    "method-override": "~2.3.0",
    "mongoose": "4.7.3",
    "morgan": "~1.4.1",
    "multer": "^1.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "~2.4.1",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-facebook": "~1.0.2",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "~1.0.2",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.6.8",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "stripe": "^4.6.0",
    "swig": "~1.4.1",
    "validator": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-env": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-karma": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.12.7",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^2.0.2",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.4.2",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "should": "^8.3.1",
    "supertest": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Noted that everything is okay to run while `NODE_ENV` is `development` in my local machine but when I change `NODE_ENV` to `production` to check the app if it is the same in `localhost` as like `heroku` deployment, yes it is the same actually that `UI` view is blank in my local machine then.

The `status code` is `304` and `200` when the `url` is reloaded that I have seen in my `network` tab as follows:

[image: network tab]

The current `heroku logs` after updating `Procfile` as follows:

```
2022-03-28T05:18:23.272847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-03-28T05:18:23.281788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-03-28T05:18:26.984666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-03-28T05:18:27.176934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-03-28T05:56:50.675089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2022-03-28T05:56:50.677137+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2022-03-28T05:56:53.724076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2022-03-28T05:56:54.672292+00:00 app[web.1]: Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2022-03-28T05:56:55.269096+00:00 app[web.1]: MEAN.JS application started on port 7785
2022-03-28T05:56:55.446764+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-03-28T05:56:57.929387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=0dcc0ddc-5ac6-40b8-93ef-32981733a8ec fwd="202.136.89.113" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1209ms status=304 bytes=251 protocol=https
2022-03-28T05:56:59.972803+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/modules/core/img/brand/favicon.ico" host=bscommerce-23.herokuapp.com request_id=3ada3e2c-16e4-4caf-a3ae-1a232b8db726 fwd="202.136.89.113" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=383ms status=304 bytes=338 protocol=https
2022-03-28T06:31:39.798121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-03-28T06:31:39.800119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-03-28T06:31:41.938049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-03-28T06:31:42.205680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Here `Exit Code 143` means that my process is being terminated by a `SIGTERM`. Is it a problem because of using free `dyno`, I am not sure but it could be!

Anyone please can solve this problem or any suggestion why it shows the blank page in `production` environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `forever` with Heroku. Please show us your `Gruntfile`. If you have a `Procfile`, please add that too.

Comment: @Chris I have added Gruntfile.js and Procfile in the question right now.

Comment: If you change your `Procfile` to simply say `web: node server.js` does the problem go away? Heroku takes care of restarting crashed processes pretty well on its own.

Comment: I edited the `Procfile` with `web: node server.js` and deployed again. Now `minUptime` warning does not come in `heroku logs` but the UI view is the same as before I mean blank page

Comment: @Chris I checked my usage of free `dyno` using command `heroku ps -a <app name>` and it returns `Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): node server.js (1)
web.1: up 2022/04/01 10:16:43 +0600 (~ 7m ago)` 
Here is 0% usage of free `dyno`. So it should not be `Idling` and `Stopping all processes with SIGTERM` but it happened.